# Clever bash solution to rearrange lines from text files?

Tags: bash, unix, text, text-files

I have 100 files, each with 1000 lines:

```
$ cat 1.txt
line1.1
line1.2
...
line1.1000

$ cat 2.txt
line2.1
line2.2
...
line2.1000

...

$ cat 100.txt
line100.1
line100.2
...
line100.1000
```

What's the easiest way to interleave them so that I end up with 1000 files, each with 100 lines, such that the first file contains all first lines from the 100 files, the second file contains all second lines from the 100 files, and so on:

```
$ cat 1.txt
line1.1
line2.1
...
line100.1

$ cat 2.txt
line1.2
line2.2
...
line100.2

...

$ cat 1000.txt
line1.1000
line2.1000
...
line100.1000
```

I could write a Python script, but I was wondering if there is a clever solution that uses UNIX tools.

Answer (score 1):

The following `paste` and `split` combo should work:

```
paste -d '\n' {1..100}.txt | split -l 100 -a 4 -d - out
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F . '{print >> $2 ".new"}' {1..100}.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

making the assumption that your output file names don't clash with you input file names, I'd use the following.  If you do have name clashes modify the following to use a temporary directory for accumulating outputfiles.

```
#!/bin/bash
for infilenum {1..100}
do
  outfilenum=1
  while read line
  do
    echo $line >> $outfilenum.out
    let outfilenum=outfilenum+1
  done < "$infilenum.txt"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `paste` to line things up?

```
$ paste 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 
line1.1 line2.1 line3.1
line1.2 line2.2 line3.2
line1.3 line2.3 line3.3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat *.txt | awk '{x=NR%i?NR%i:i;print > x".txt"}' i=1000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{if(count==1000){count=0;}count++;print >count".txt"}' *.txt
```

tested succcessfully with two lines:

```
> cat 1.txte
1
2
> cat 2.txte
1
2
> awk '{if(count==2){count=0;}count++;print >count".txt"}' *.txte
> cat 1.txt
1
1
> cat 2.txt
2
2
>
```

so you just have to change from `count==2` to `count==1000` since your files have 1000 lines.